# QR codes in php without using the now deprecated Google Charts API

Tags: php, qr-code

Does anyone know of a PHP class which generates QR codes on your server instead of relying on the now deprecated Google Charts API which will not always be in existence.

I'm also thinking that bulk QR code generation will be faster if it's done on the server.

I would also consider a client based JS or Jquery solution to the problem.

Comment: Could use another api: http://www.sparqcode.com/static/QRGenAPI (quick google search, but there are others)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres this one...its for javascript though...

http://d-project.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/misc/qrcode/js/

or this....PHP lib

http://phpqrcode.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks, both will be useful to me.

Comment: The first link now requires authentication.

Comment: First link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

I've just started using [visuallead](http://open.visualead.com/). The syntax is pretty simple. This syntax:

```
http://open.visualead.com/?data=paper.exchange&size=110&type=png
```

Yields this:

```html
<img src="http://open.visualead.com/?data=paper.exchange&size=110&type=png"/>
```