# i am trying to create a qr code using google chart api.. Need to take text as input and convert it to qrcode

Tags: jquery, html

i am trying to create a qr code using google chart api.. Need to take text as input and convert it to qrcode

trying to toy with this piece of code , but some how cant get it to work. Not really an expert at this. So any help will be great.thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://net-raft.com/plugins/jquery/toggle_input/ToggleInput.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script>
 </head>

 <body>
 <input id="myID" type="text" value="mypassword"></br>
 <button type="button">click</button>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

 $("button").click(function () {

var myattr = $("#myID").attr("type");
$("#myID").Toggle_Input(myattr);

 });

  });

  $(document).ready(function (){
 var url = $(location).attr('href');

 $("div").html("<img src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=" + url + "&choe=UTF-8' alt='QR code' />\n"); 
 }); 

</script>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add your qr code placeholder: `<div id="div"></div>`. The next problem is Google chart api QR generator is deprecated, you can use your own generator implemented in PHP, or use some reliable online service, refer to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16976025/qr-codes-in-php-without-using-the-now-deprecated-google-charts-api)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://net-raft.com/plugins/jquery/toggle_input/ToggleInput.js" type="text/javascript"> 
</script>
 </head>

 <body>

<div id="div"></div>

 <input id="myID" type="text" value="mypassword"></br>
 <button type="button">click</button>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

 $("button").click(function () {

var myattr = $("#myID").attr("type");
$("#myID").Toggle_Input(myattr);

 });

  });

  $(document).ready(function (){
 var url = $(location).attr('href');

 $("div").html("<img src='https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=300x300&cht=qr&chl=" + url + "&choe=UTF-8' alt='QR code' />\n"); 
 }); 

</script>
</body>
 </html>
```

Comment: another question @gabonator on a different tangent all together. if i had to retrieve some data from firebase using the same input field . how would i display that. i have the code to query it, just need to know how to display it

Comment: Please note that this API is now deprecated and does not work any more. Please use the actively maintained Google Charts API instead.